# Как выявить экплойт в этой модели чата?

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, уязвимости

есть модель чата :

```
<?php

  class Chat extends Model {

    public $table = '#prefix#rooms';
    public $key   = 'id';

    public static $limit = 5;

    /**
     * Последние 10 сообщений в чате;
     *
     * Если указан $room_id, значит запрос со стороны админа
     */
    public static function getMessages($page = 1, $room_id = false) {
      if ( $room_id === false ) {
        $room_id = Client::get('id_chat');
      }

      $offset = ((int)$page - 1) * self::$limit;

      $msgs = DB::fetch('
        select
          id, admin, body, ts, user
        from
          #prefix#messages
        where
          id_room = ? order by ts desc limit ' . self::$limit . ' offset ' . $offset, (int)$room_id);

      if ( $msgs ) {
        // получаем вложения для каждого сообщения

        foreach( $msgs as $i => $item ) {
          $msgs[ $i ]->attachments = DB::shift_array('select attachment from #prefix#attachments where id_message = ? order by attachment asc', $item->id);
        }
      }

      return $msgs;
    }

    /**
     * Общее количество сообщений в комнате;
     *
     * Если указан $id, значит запрос со стороны админа
     */
    public static function totalMessages($room_id = false) {
      if ( $room_id === false ) {
        $room_id = Client::get('id_chat');
      }

      return DB::shift('select count(*) as c from #prefix#messages where id_room = ?', (int)$room_id);
    }

    /**
     * Добавление нового сообщения в чат
     *
     * @param string $mesage - сообщение
     * @param bool   $admin  - ответ администратора или пользователя
     *
     * @return bool | object
     */
    public static function addMessage(&$data, $admin = false, $id_room = false) {
      if ( $id_room === false ) {
        $id_room = (int)Client::get('id_chat');
      }

      $message   = preg_replace('#\n#ui', '<br />', htmlspecialchars($data['body']));
      $ts        = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s');
      $id_client = DB::shift('select id from #prefix#clients where id_chat = ? limit 1', $id_room);

      // добавляем сообщение
      $res = DB::execute(
        'insert into #prefix#messages (id_room, admin, body, ts) values(?, ?, ?, ?)',
        (int)$id_room,
        (int)$admin,
        $message,
        $ts
      );

      if ( $admin ) {
        $data['attachments'] = array();

        if ( $_FILES && $_FILES['attachments'] && $_FILES['attachments']['tmp_name'][0] ) {
          // загрузка вложений админом

          $uploaddir = get_document_root() . 'u_files/' . $id_client . '/chat/';

          if ( !is_dir($uploaddir) ) {
            mkdir($uploaddir, 0755, true);
          }

          if ( !is_writable($uploaddir) ) {
            chmod($uploaddir, 0755);
          }

          foreach( $_FILES['attachments']['name'] as $k => $name ) {
            $ext = strtolower(preg_replace('#^.*\.(\w+)$#ui', '$1', $name));

            if ( !in_array(
              $ext,
              [
                'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png',
                'txt', 'csv', 'doc', 'docx', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'ppt', 'pptx', 'pdf', 'odt', 'odp', 'ods',
                'zip', 'rar',
                'mp4', 'avi', 'mpg', 'wma', 'flv', 'webm'
              ]
            )
            ) {
              continue;
            }

            $filename = preg_replace('#^(.*)\.\w+$#ui', '$1', $name);
            $filename = URLify::filter($filename) . '.' . $ext;

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachments']['tmp_name'][ $k ], $uploaddir . $filename);
            $data['attachments'] [] = '/u_files/' . $id_client . '/chat/' . $filename;

            // права на сам файл
            chmod(get_document_root() . '/u_files/' . $id_client . '/chat/' . $filename, 0644);
          }
        }
      }

      if ( isset($data['attachments']) && $data['attachments'] ) {
        // если есть вложения, прикрепляем их к сообщению

        $message_id = DB::last_id();

        foreach( $data['attachments'] as $attachment ) {
          $attachment=conf('e_url', 'url').$attachment;
          DB::execute('insert into #prefix#attachments (id_message, attachment) values(?, ?)', $message_id, $attachment);
        }
      }

      // обновляем счетчик непрочитанных сообщений для пользователя
      if ( !$admin ) {
        DB::execute('update #prefix#rooms set unread = ? where id = ? limit 1', ($admin ? 2 : 1), $id_room);
      }

      if ( $res ) {
        if ( !$admin ) {
          user\Notices::admin_newChatMessage(Client::$user);
        } else {
          user\Notices::client_newChatMessage($id_room);
        }

        return (object)array(
          'admin'       => $admin,
          'body'        => $message,
          'attachments' => $data['attachments'] ? $data['attachments'] : false,
          'ts'          => $ts
        );
      }

      return false;
    }
    /**
     * Добавление нового сообщения в чат версия 2 с указаним ид пользователя
     *
     * @param string $mesage - сообщение
     * @param bool   $admin  - ответ администратора или пользователя
     *
     * @return bool | object
     */
     public static function addMessage2(&$data, $admin = false, $id_room = false, $user = 0 ) {
      if ( $id_room === false ) {
        $id_room = (int)Client::get('id_chat');
      }

      $message   = preg_replace('#\n#ui', '<br />', htmlspecialchars($data['body']));
      $ts        = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s');
      $id_client = DB::shift('select id from #prefix#clients where id_chat = ? limit 1', $id_room);

      // добавляем сообщение
      $res = DB::execute(
        'insert into #prefix#messages (id_room, admin, body, ts, user) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
        (int)$id_room,
        (int)$admin,
        $message,
        $ts,
    $user
      );

      if ( $admin ) {
        $data['attachments'] = array();

        if ( $_FILES && $_FILES['attachments'] && $_FILES['attachments']['tmp_name'][0] ) {
          // загрузка вложений админом

          $uploaddir = get_document_root() . 'u_files/' . $id_client . '/chat/';

          if ( !is_dir($uploaddir) ) {
            mkdir($uploaddir, 0755, true);
          }

          if ( !is_writable($uploaddir) ) {
            chmod($uploaddir, 0755);
          }

          foreach( $_FILES['attachments']['name'] as $k => $name ) {
            $ext = strtolower(preg_replace('#^.*\.(\w+)$#ui', '$1', $name));

            if ( !in_array(
              $ext,
              [
                'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png',
                'txt', 'csv', 'doc', 'docx', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'ppt', 'pptx', 'pdf', 'odt', 'odp', 'ods',
                'zip', 'rar',
                'mp4', 'avi', 'mpg', 'wma', 'flv', 'webm'
              ]
            )
            ) {
              continue;
            }

            $filename = preg_replace('#^(.*)\.\w+$#ui', '$1', $name);
            $filename = URLify::filter($filename) . '.' . $ext;

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachments']['tmp_name'][ $k ], $uploaddir . $filename);
            $data['attachments'] [] = '/u_files/' . $id_client . '/chat/' . $filename;

            // права на сам файл
            chmod(get_document_root() . '/u_files/' . $id_client . '/chat/' . $filename, 0644);
          }
        }
      }

      if ( isset($data['attachments']) && $data['attachments'] ) {
        // если есть вложения, прикрепляем их к сообщению

        $message_id = DB::last_id();

        foreach( $data['attachments'] as $attachment ) {
          $attachment=conf('easyship_url', 'url').$attachment;
          DB::execute('insert into #prefix#attachments (id_message, attachment) values(?, ?)', $message_id, $attachment);
        }
      }

      // обновляем счетчик непрочитанных сообщений для пользователя
      if ( !$admin ) {
        DB::execute('update #prefix#rooms set unread = ? where id = ? limit 1', ($admin ? 2 : 1), $id_room);
      }

      if ( $res ) {
        if ( !$admin ) {
          user\Notices::admin_newChatMessage(Client::$user);
        } else {
          user\Notices::client_newChatMessage($id_room);
        }

        return (object)array(
          'admin'       => $admin,
          'body'        => $message,
          'attachments' => $data['attachments'] ? $data['attachments'] : false,
          'ts'          => $ts
        );
      }

      return false;
    }

    /**
     * Подсчитываем кол-во непрочитанных пользователем сообщений
     */
    public static function getUnreadMessages() {
      $id_room = (int)Client::get('id_chat');

      $res = DB::single("select unread, last_check from #prefix#chat_rooms where id = ? limit 1", $id_room);
      if ( $res && $res->unread == 2 ) {
        // если стоит отметка, о новых сообщениях для пользователя

        return DB::shift("
          select
            count(*) as c
          from
            #prefix#chat_messages
          where
            id_room = ? and admin = 1
            and id > (select id from #prefix#messages where id_room = ? and admin = 0 order by ts desc limit 1)
            and ts > ?
          order by ts desc", $id_room, $id_room, $res->last_check);
      }

      return false;
    }

    /**
     * Сбрасываем флаг непрочитанных сообщений;
     * frontend
     */
    public static function resetUnread() {
      $id_room = (int)Client::get('id_chat');

      /**
       * Сбрасываем только, если комната была помечена,
       * как непрочитанная для клиента(не для админа)
       */
      DB::execute("update #prefix#chat_rooms set unread = 0, last_check = ? where id = ? and unread = 2 limit 1", gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s'), $id_room);
    }

    /**
     * Перемещает файлы из временной папки в папку пользователя
     *
     * @param array $attachments - tmp attachments
     *
     * @return array - real attachments
     */
    public static function mvTmpUploads(&$attachments = array()) {
      $root       = getcwd();
      $user_dir   = $root . '/userfiles/' . Client::get('id') . '/';
      $session_id = session_id();

      /**
       * все файлы загружаемые пользователем до отправки сообщения в чате,
       * находятся во временной дирректории с именем его сессии;
       */
      $tmp_dir = "$root/tmp/$session_id/";

      if ( !is_dir($user_dir) ) {
        @mkdir($user_dir, 0755, true);
      } elseif ( !is_writable($user_dir) ) {
        @chmod($user_dir, 0755);
      }

      $res = array();
      if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach( $attachments as $item ) {
          if ( @is_file($tmp_dir . $item) ) {

            $i            = 1;
            $new_filename = $item;

            /**
             * При переносе файла из временной дирректории в папку пользователя,
             * может случиться, что файл с таким именем уже существует,
             * поэтому ставим номер копии в имени файла;
             *
             * @todo наверно while без выхода не очень хорошо
             */
            while( @is_file($user_dir . $new_filename) ) {
              $new_filename = preg_replace("#^(.+)\.(\w+)$#ui", "$1-$i.$2", $item);

              ++$i;
            }

            if ( @rename($tmp_dir . $item, $user_dir . $new_filename) ) {
              $res [] = '/u_files/' . Client::get('id') . '/' . $new_filename;
            }
          }
        }
      }

      // @todo сборщик мусора

      return $res;
    }
  }

?>
```

Предположительно через эту форму, был скомпроментирован сайт, пользователь смог удалить свою переписку(без прямого доступа к базе, по логам в неё не входили, через админку также не редактировалось, т.к все изменения записываются ).

База mariadb 5.56
php 7.0

Как можно отследить и устранить уязвимость?

Comment: Спросить у пользователя, который это сделал?

Comment: это мошенник, очевидно же ну)

Comment: почему вы думаете, что через этот файл? мб начать с того файла,где присутствуют `delete` запросы?

Comment: Запросов с delete нету вообще